# A lot of loop errors when using form's radio

Tags: html, jquery, forms, radio-button

Hello guys i have a problem while trying to use the 'radio' input in a form - every time i put my mouse on one of the radio buttons i get like 400 errors saying

```
Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ ...cApp.php
```

I have no idea if its somehow related to the jQuery code i tried to use because even when i delete all the jQuery code the errors are coming out!

here is the code:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="cApp" autocomplete="off" />
  <div class="appTargetLabel">
  Target:
  <label for=""><input type="radio" name="clientCheck" value="self" checked="checked" /> Self</label>
  <label for=""><input type="radio" name="clientCheck" value="client" /> Client</label>
  </div>
```

Again - even when i completely remove all the jquery code i still get these errors.

Comment: your code is not complete, show the full page with includes and all javascript you have in it.

Comment: Is a line number given for the error?

Comment: @Davide Piras - I said that even when i completly delete all the javascript it still shows me the error, maybe it has something to do with cache?
Šime Vidas - Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with getElementById() and missing IDs. I don't know where this error messages is shown, but I would try to use IDs and connect the labels to them:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="cApp" autocomplete="off" />
  <div class="appTargetLabel">
  Target:
  <label for="i1"><input id="i1" type="radio" name="clientCheck" value="self" checked="checked" /> Self</label>
  <label for="i2"><input id="i2" type="radio" name="clientCheck" value="client" /> Client</label>
  </div>
</form>
```